# How can one do their own algorithmic trading (does Robinhood and/or Webull provide a REST API)?

Tags: investing, trading, stock-markets, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

In order to do algorithmic trading one needs more than just access to a commercial app like Robinhood or Webull. Their tools give individuals access to a range of tools, but all the execution of trades is done by them. What if an individual is doing their own analysis on markets and wants their scripts to automatically make a trade based on their own algorithms? Is this possible through a REST API provided by any of these electronic trading platforms?

Comment: This is something you could easily google. But, many brokerages do offer a rest API for trading. TD Ameritrade, for example, provides an API for trading.

Comment: @DoYouEvenCodeBro Well then maybe, just maybe, the question is being asked to get information from people who actually do this. You know, nuanced information that you can’t find on Google.

Comment: I don't know what kind of nuanced information you are hoping to get but I suspect your question is too broad, general, and easily searchable to receive any information in an answer that "can't be found on Google", as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to do algorithmic trading one needs more than just access to a commercial app like Robinhood or Webull.

Correct, while it may be possible (perhaps it violates their TOS) to algorithmically trade using an app-based broker, you will have a much easier time simply trading with a broker that provides a documented trading API.

> all the execution of trades is done by them.

Technically, neither Robinhood nor Webull execute their own trades. If you are interested in this topic I suggest reading about "Payment for Order Flow". Basically, a market maker pays the brokerage for order flow, and makes a small profit by actually executing the trades. The broker doesn't execute the trades themselves.

> What if an individual is doing their own analysis on markets and wants their scripts to automatically make a trade based on their own algorithms? Is this possible through a REST API provided by any of these electronic trading platforms?

You are looking for a brokerage which proviedes an API you can use for trading. You might want to use a search such as https://www.google.com/search?q=stock+brokers+with+rest+api to find one that looks suitable.

Anecdotally, I have used TD Ameritrade's API, https://developer.tdameritrade.com/apis, for a few trading projects and found it perfectly suitable.

Comment: Excellent,Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At least one broker has an API: [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/trading/ib-api.php)

> Use our modern REST API to trade, monitor and manage your IBKR
> account.